# Copy canvas from one page to another without crossing max character limit

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to play a video in HTML video element and take snapshot on pause. The snapshot is displayed on the page inside a canvas. Now I want the same snap to appear on another page and for this I am trying to encode the snapshot in base 64 using `toDataUrl()` method & pass it through URL.

But the maximum length of URL can be 2048 char while the output of toDataUrl is much bigger. How to proceed?

Working fine:

```
video.addEventListener('pause', function(){ 
                        $(this).hide();
                        $("#canvas1").show();
                        draw( video, thecanvas, img); 
        }, false);

function draw(video,thecanvas,img){

        var context = thecanvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(video,0,0,thecanvas.width,thecanvas.height);
        var dataURL = thecanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',.1);
        img.setAttribute('src',dataURL);

    }
```

Not working: The function to direct to another page

```
function toskuentry(){
    var imgsrc = $('#thumbnail_img').attr('src');
    window.location.href = "sku_entry.php?imgsrc="+imgsrc;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass it through the URL, use HTML5 Web Storage. You can use either `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`:

```
function toskuentry(){
    localStorage.setItem("img", $('#thumbnail_img').attr('src'));
}
```

On the next page you can access it by `localStorage.getItem("img");`.

Comment: Thanks spencer .. You saved my life !! 
Now you can vote up 
:)

Answer (score 0):

One good option would be to use Firebase. They have an example of doing that.
https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#session/n24v8lvnltc

Firebase uses local storage when offline, so that means you could also use local storage if you didn't want to use Firebase.

something like

```
localStorage["data"] = dataURL;

//...other page
var dataURL = JSON.parse(localStorage["data"]);
```